# The tag Glitch now has a game

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It is a [game](http://www.glitch.com/) now. Do we need to break the [existing synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/synonyms)?

Comment: Can we come up with a question for this game first, so that we can also have clarifying tag excerpts to go with it? I guess that they can be tagged `glitch-the-game` in the meantime

Comment: Ideally two questions, so that we can keep the tag alive.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31239/how-to-efficiently-collect-grain

Comment: Maybe make `glitches` point to `bug` and have good tag wikis to distinguish it from `glitch`?

Answer (score 1):

This has been now done. I'm kinda worried as the 'glitch' synonym had 16 renames when I deleted it, but the wiki excerpt should help now, and even if people get this wrong we can always retag.